# IdentityServer: fetch requests fails after some time because user gets authenticated again

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, identityserver4

I have an asp.net core web application, which is connected to an identityserver. I can log in and log out without any problem. My problem is, I have many fetch requests to update some data in my page without reloading the page. After some time, the fetch requests get forwarded to the endpoint "signin-oidc" and it returns an Html error!

the fetch request is as follows:

```
function ReqeustImageFromServer(guid, controller, action) {
var ajx = function () {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
     $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
         url: PAGE_BASE_PATH + "/" + controller + "/" + action + "?GUID=" + guid ,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
           resolve(data)
        },
        error: function (err) {
           reject(err);
        }
     });
  });
}
return ajx();
}
```

The error caught by the try catch at the fetch request is as follows:

```
{"readyState":4,"responseText":"<html><head><meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge' /><base target='_self'/></head><body><form method='post' action='https://tu_elam2020/flowchart/signin-oidc'><input type='hidden' name='code' value='FD644F046911C8141FA455C74700DDB925020ECB843936E1B177B227B33D93F2' />\n<input type='hidden' name='scope' value='openid profile roles offline_access IdentityServerApi' />\n<input type='hidden' name='state' value='CfDJ8Ahux529-J9FqVkcJ6VRjkmuYUrfgO7yb64nPlQQNx1bCz2evlk0fy6BhaWa2tmzc7YPGDbq3nTbQMfbZhR1Gbz7F0OcqzqPpPPBHiejRjkzg5C3_brtc1ebGDNdNvHxvUTpcu6AASzXzAjTmzr9ICh_pQuGGcH8bqJcoIhXKdnStqGA5hD8Afquvi7dTWIY83CCibp9FmI9NgVnpZ2l3m48EXhllZyURF6wCDrz_LuAOhOoUf3J4HYPGgZ7fUuNbLmfh56kp6y9C1CvN8A7SHlAbSyEZHaVq1E84dgouVUmRQ8BNl9FlAynHbUxLH9pFo5SxhFjqqr3NWs8cpZ8n0jHCEcu7KM3Qvs6Ph6Mrs2Gr699xCveUS7VbjnlhFe9D36q9d1TmeCyPRc_1X2y0t3yEDI42XCHVQeZKLxbINsDfxZjkwmYZOgunexIH8laUx8ehhx9-JmE0KDVodQ_xWNdTrEph3NXeVuxXMO5rKnfyy43YjhIq5AN5YMpQlScPA' />\n<input type='hidden' name='session_state' value='zfffMZKIbc_SOqDfN9Xnt19T3Y_hm7do5677r6BCNoU.7D6C35D47AAAED1B6945DE2BD29D415D' />\n<noscript><button>Click to continue</button></noscript></form><script>window.addEventListener('load', function(){document.forms[0].submit();});</script></body></html>","status":200,"statusText":"parsererror"}
```

but when I redo the action to trigger the fetch request it works normally!

I don't know how should I handle this? I assume this occurs when the identityToken expires and it renews itself. But even so, how can I let my fetch requests continue doing what it has to do?

Hope you can help me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using OpenIdConnect? Or just basic Auth? OpenIdConnect is the easier route to take because they have callbacks in OWIN where you can handle adding the tokens to claims.

Comment: I find two links about signin-oidc error message , Hope they can help you. [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45458612/identityserver-4-openidconnect-redirect-to-external-sign-in-url),[link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58739915/identity-server-404-after-login-stuck-on-signin-oidc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you see in the response is the **authorization code** that IdentityServer is returning back to the browser. The browser is then meant to automatically submit the form data back to the client so that the user can login.

What you see is part of the flow when a human user is logging in and you should not see that when you make an API call.

When you make an API request, you should just return status code 401/403 and not challenge the user to login again.

This is because you have the API and web site in the same service.

The main problem is that your backend is challenging the OpenIDConnect handler instead of the JwtBearer handler when the user is not allowed to access the resource you are requesting.(you do use AddJwtBearer?)

In your fetch, should that always be allowed or should it be protected using JWT tokens?

If it should be public you need to add the AllowAnonymous attribute to the controller.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Your reply is very helpful! Yes, i think this is the problem, that i have the API and the website in same service. 
Currently i can't change the location of the webpi. 

I can make it public by adding allowAnonymous but how it should act, if i do want protect the fetch request just for registered users? I need  to let this authrization process happend in background and if it is okay then continue doing the the fetch request.
- Which time is resposible for the re login of the user in this case? 
I've extended the AccessTokenLifetime and it still occures.

Comment: well, you use IdentityServer, so you could use the issued access tokens to control the access to the API but , as you are using JavaScript, you should consider the BFF pattern mentioned here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EJeZ3YNnqz8&ab_channel=NDCConferences